# Capture multiline output as array in bash

Tags: bash

If `inner.sh` is

```
#...
echo first
echo second
echo third
```

And `outer.sh` is

```
var=`./inner.sh`
# only wants to use "first"...
```

How can `var` be split by whitespace?

Comment: Why not to use `for word in $var; do` ?

Comment: $EarlGray I would guess bash has a more direct way.

Comment: this reminded me of bash "emulation" of string(3) [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-23/bash/examples/scripts.noah/string.bash?txt). I'm sure you'll find a strtok() there :)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Try this:

```
var=($(./inner.sh))

# And then test the array with:

echo ${var[0]}
echo ${var[1]}
echo ${var[2]}
```

**Output:**

```
first
second
third
```

**Explanation:**

- You can make an array in bash by doing `var=(first second third)`, for example.
- `$(./inner.sh)` runs the `inner.sh` script, which prints out `first`, `second`, and `third` on separate lines. Since we don't didn't put double quotes around `$(...)`, they get lumped onto the same line, but separated by spaces, so you end up with what it looks like in the previous bullet point.

Comment: check out the last answer, this method was good for the question, but if you  need something more (like keeping the separators in tact, calling a function automatically after each line is read, etc) then mapfile by far is more powerful + it's super efficient, ive tested this with many programs and i've never had to wait long even for files that get to be in 100,000's of lines. Usually it's instant assuming you are using local storage :)

Comment: This answer actually split **words** not **lines** into array elements. Technically it answer the question asked, but not the more general case. Test case : `var=( $( echo "1 2 3" ; echo "4 5 6" ) ) ; echo ${var[0]}` I expected "1 2 3", it yields "1". Depends on your use case. `mapfile` does what I need.

Comment: @sampson-chen how do I reference a range subset of elements? var[0:2] doesn't work

Comment: as @StéphaneGourichon pointed out, this splits words not lines, so this does not work with empty lines, they are simply ignored which effectively screws up the order of lines in the array

Comment: Didn't work for me. I had to prefix the `var=( ...` command with `IFS=$'\n' ` and in the next line unset the internal field separator of bash with `unset IFS`.

Answer (score 61):

Don't forget the builtin `mapfile`. It's definitely the most efficient in your case: If you want to slurp the whole file in an array, the fields of which will be the lines output by `./inner.sh`, do

```
mapfile -t array < <(./inner.sh)
```

Then you'll have the first row in `${array[0]}`, etc...

For more info on this builtin and all the possible options:

```
help mapfile
```

If you just need the first line in a variable called `firstline`, do

```
read -r firstline < <(./inner.sh)
```

These are definitely the most efficient ways!

This small benchmark will prove it:

```
$ time mapfile -t array < <(for i in {0..100000}; do echo "fdjsakfjds$i"; done)

real    0m1.514s
user    0m1.492s
sys 0m0.560s
$ time array=( $(for i in {0..100000}; do echo "fdjsakfjds$i"; done) )

real    0m2.045s
user    0m1.844s
sys 0m0.308s
```

If you only want the first word (with space delimiter) of the first line output by `./inner.sh`, the most efficient way is

```
read firstword _ < <(./inner.sh)
```

Comment: imo: the best answer here, mapfile by far is faster than the other methods, i was working with output lines > 14,000 entries, mapfile worked almost instantaneously rather than using an external program, i use the rule of thumb to never involve other programs to do the work that the language is supposed to do for itself, and bash is no exception, that rule goes double when working with variables.

Comment: ***WTF*** is mapfile?_  `brew info mapfile || echo "found $(brew desc -s mapfile | wc -l) references to mapfile"`
-> **`Error: No available formula for mapfile`
`found        0 references to mapfile`** let me go on... `sh-3.2$ mapfile` -> **`sh: mapfile: command not found`**

Comment: @alexgray `mapfile` is a Bash≥4 builtin. Not available in POSIX shells or Bash<4. Seems you're running 3.2; you're screwed. Unless you install a more recent version of Bash.

Comment: This answer indeed splits **lines** into an array. Test case: `mapfile -t var < <(  echo "1 2 3" ; echo "4 5 6" ) ; echo ${var[1]}` correctly yields `4 5 6`.

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)`: `-bash: mapfile: command not found`; apparently, the built-in is [also called `readarray`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile), however: `-bash: readarray: command not found`. Both command variants seem to be a Linux-only thing, they do exist on `GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. So much for cross platform.

Comment: @ssc: I doubt they removed `mapfile` from 4.4.12 on OS X. How are you calling `mapfile`? are you really calling it with 4.4.12? When calling it, try `echo "$BASH_VERSION"; mapfile ...` to output the version prior to calling `mapfile`.

Comment: I'm calling it on both OSs in the same way; results as shown. I don't see how `echo`ing the bash version would change anything. To relieve your doubt, I suggest you log into OS X and try for yourself.

Comment: @ssc That's to be sure that you're using the correct version of Bash when calling `mapfile` — just because it's a common source of error on OS X. And I have no idea why your error is prefixed with `-bash`. Sorry, I don't have OS X available. Moreover, there are lots of people using `mapfile` on OS X around here, so I suspect that you're the one doing something wrong. I was just trying to help you, starting with the basic, suggesting that you double check the version number. Now I'm sorry I can't be of any further help.

Comment: For the edification of anyone curious, you can also use a here-string instead of process substitution if you feed it a newline-delimited (or whatever your IFS is) string.  In this case it would look like this:

`mapfile -t my_array <<< "$my_string"`.

Comment: (Correction for my previous comment: `mapfile` _does not use_ `IFS`.  It uses newlines by default.  To customize the delimiter use the `-d` argument.)

Comment: For people wondering why commands like read, readarray/mapfile... bring along a process substitution <(...) instead of a straightforward pipe, it's well explained here [Can't pipe in bash's “mapfile” … but why?](https://superuser.com/questions/1348948/cant-pipe-in-bashs-mapfile-but-why/1348950)

Comment: @boweeb The result array is not the same when the feeding string is empty : no items with a process substitution vs. 1 empty item with a here-string.

Comment: @luciole75w gtk -- good catch!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `read` builtin will return a non-zero exit status upon encountering an EOF, so if you have set `-e` somewhere in your shell script as the [_Bash Strict Mode_](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) document suggests, you better mask the exit code of `read`, e. g.: `read -a myarray -d '' -r <<< "${raw_content}" || true`.

Answer (score 11):

You're not splitting on whitespaces but rather on newlines.
Give this a whirl:

```
IFS=$'
'

var=$(./echo.sh)
echo $var | awk '{ print $1 }'
unset IFS
```

Comment: how do I then access the elements of `var`?

Comment: `newvar = $(echo $var | awk '{ print $1 }')` and access $newvar

Comment: thanks, I looked for this and found your nice snippet. You can also write IFS=$'\n' for better readability, and put the two commands on one line without ; between them like: "IFS=$'\n' var=$(./echo.sh)" so you do not need to unset IFS afterwards