# Bash syntax mapfile input redirection

Tags: bash, redirect, input

Could someone explain me this syntax for mapfile input redirection?

```
mapfile -t array < <(./inner.sh)
```

(from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13825568/874188) by gniourf_gniourf)

As I understand, the first "<" is to take input from the output of whatever is on the right side of it. But what is the <( ... ) syntax? Why is the second "<" required?

Comment: It's called [Process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: Thanks. so I looked at the link you mentioned. In that, the example for 'wc' uses a single <( ... ). So why is the extra "<" required in the mapfile case for taking in input?

Comment: From the perspective of the process wc, the example uses `wc filename` syntax. `<(...)` is process substitution syntax. From logical perspective, `<(...)` gets expanded to a filename, & anything read from that file is the output of command between the parenthesis. You can check other examples on that page or try your own examples.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason the [linked example](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) looks like this:

```
wc <(cat /usr/share/dict/linux.words)
```

And the [mapfile answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823706/capture-multiline-output-as-array-in-bash) looks like this:

```
mapfile -t array < <(./inner.sh)
```

Is because of the difference in the `wc` and `mapfile` commands and how the substituted process needs to be given to command.

As anishsane says the expansion of `<(command)` is a filename and can be used anywhere a filename can be used.

`wc` takes filenames as arguments so it can be used directly as an argument.

`mapfile` reads from standard input so to get it to read from a specific file you use you redirect standard input from the file `</path/to/somefile` but as I just said the expansion of `<(command)` is a filename so you can use that in the input redirection.

However, you cannot just concat the two bits directly (the way you can with a file name/path) because `<<` is also a valid shell construct (a here document) and that would be ambiguous to the shell. So to avoid that you need to space out the two `<` characters and end up with `< <(command)` (which is analogous to `< file` which is perfectly legal).