# Read file sed the line before send the params into array

Tags: bash, shell

i try to remove some string of my result before to send them on my array . i tried different stuff but i didn't found  it :( 
actually in my $LOGFILE i've something like that :

```
STATUS          TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAM
--------------- -------------------
AVAILABLE       2017.10.18 18:00:30
AVAILABLE       2017.10.24 18:00:26
```

**And i try to have only the date 2017.10.18 18:00:30**

```
   function read_file {                                                                                                                                                                                           
      while read line;do                                                                                                                                                                                           
         arr[$i]="$line"                                                                                                                                                                                           
          i=$((i+1))                                                                                                                                                                                               
     #   $line | sed s/"-"//g | sed s/"STATUS"//g | sed s/'TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAM'//g | sed s/"AVAILABLE"//g | sed '/^ *$/d'                                                                                         
       done< $LOGFILE                                                                                                                                                                                              

       printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `grep` be acceptable?

```
grep -o '[0-9].*' $LOGFILE
```

Output:

```
2017.10.18 18:00:30
2017.10.24 18:00:26
```

Use `mapfile` to capture the output in an array.

```
$ mapfile -t arr < <(grep -o '[0-9].*' $LOGFILE)

$ echo ${arr[0]}
2017.10.18 18:00:30

$ echo ${arr[1]}
2017.10.24 18:00:26
```

Many thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823706/capture-multiline-output-as-array-in-bash#13825568).

Comment: unfortunatly i've to play with an ARRAY because maybe later i will have to call by an INDEX