# Save all changed file names to a list in bash

Tags: bash, git

I want to get all changed files from

```
$git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2
```

and save them to an array variable in bash, but when I use:

```
files=$(git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2)
```

for some reason it saves all file names as a string with space delimiter, so when I type

```
$echo ${files[0]}
```

I get all file names as a single String, and

```
$echo ${files[1]}
```

is empty. So how do I save each file name as an array element, so that I could iterate over them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [capture a multiline output as array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824135/6309)

```
files=($(git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2))
```

Then `echo ${files[0]}` or `echo ${files[1]}` would work as expected.